# How to Subtract Two Integer Values in Different Tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to achieve subtracting two integer values different tables, this is what I have tried so far.

```
Controller:
$amount = DB::table('shipping_datas')->where('amount')->first();
$payment = DB::table('payments')->where('amount')->first();
$balance = $amount - $payment;

Blade:
{{ $balance }}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: While it's not very clear what you are asking for, I reckon that you both your variables ($amount & $payment) query the same table: DB::table('shipping')->where('amount');

Comment: What is the problem? Can't get results? Same in 2 tables in code. You didn't add `->first()` after the query. You cannot get results.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply, Pls Wait

Comment: Both are same `DB::table('shipping')->where('amount');`  actually question is not clear. Would you please clarify more, what you try to achieve?

Comment: Ok Sorry I didnt Saw Thank you

Comment: I already Edited It

Comment: `->where('amount')->first();` but how your system know which row? May be you missing `->where('amount', 100)` or `->where('id', 1)`

Comment: Can we chat on facebook

Comment: check this you can do with one query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456128/subtract-2-columns-from-different-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$amount = DB::table('shipping_datas')->pluck('amount')->sum();
$payment = DB::table('payments')->pluck('amount')->sum();
$balance = $amount - $payment;
```

i think its work.

Comment: This one works, you can also use it instead of looping through the amount